# unusual behavior of strings

Tags: c, string

what makes the gets function here store the 1st input string here in pt[1] instead of pt[0] and exits loop after reading p-1 strings, if scanf is used it reads p strings but prints the 1st string (pt[0]) as a blank space ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
{
  int c,i,j,p,k;
  char d[100],pt[1000][1000];
  scanf("%d",&c);
  for(i=0;i<=c-1;i++)
  {
    scanf(" %c",&d[i]);
  }

  scanf("%d",&p);

  for(i=0;i<=p-1;i++)
  {
    scanf(" %c",&d[i]);
  }

  scanf("%d",&p);

  for(i=0;i<=p-1;i++)
  {
    gets(pt[i]);
  }
       /*the first string is stored in pt[1] instead of pt[0] and loop terminates after reading p-1 strings */
```

Comment: Don't use `gets`, it has been deprecated because it's unsafe since the C99 standard, and was removed completely from the C11 standard.

Comment: Avoid declaring large amounts of data locally, on the stack. This code has great potential for stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous `scanf` call leaves the newline in the input buffer, which means the first `gets` call reads that newline as an empty line.

The easiest way to solve this is a single `fgets` call to get the "rest" of the line between the `scanf` call and the loop.

Comment: i thought that was only for the case of c and some spl variables others like d and f automatically eliminates whitespaces , so it should not be a case here as clearly the previous input here was a integer.

Comment: @SumitKumar Most formats reads and discard *leading* white-space, no format reads and discard trailing.

Comment: yeah..that was indeed the problem.. and putting a space ahead of %s in scanf solves it too ..thanks

Comment: Concerning "no format reads and discard trailing."  Does not `scanf("%d ", &c)` discard trailing whitespace?

Comment: @chux Maybe I should have been clearer, I meant that no *format specifier* automatically discards trailing spaces. And adding a trailing space to the format string have its problems too, as then one needs to input something *not* a white-space for `scanf` (et al.) to be satisfied and return.

Comment: @SumitKumar Explicitly skipping leading space is only needed for the `"%c"`, `"%["` and `"%n"` format specifiers, all other format specifiers (including `"%s"`) does it automatically. See e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for more information.